# how to calculate the gradient in python numpy

Tags: numpy, scipy, gradient, sympy

i have to implement the Stochastic Gradient Descent in Numpy. So I've to define the gradient of this function E:

[image]

In which also f and g are defined in the image.
I've no idea of how to do this, I tried with Sympy and numdifftools but these libraries give me some errors.
How could I write the gradient of the function E?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you mean this?

```
import numpy as np

# G function
def g(x):
    return np.tanh(x/2)

# F function
def f(x, N, n, v, g):
    sumf = 0
    for j in range(1, N):
        sumi = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            sumi += w[j, i]*x[i] - b[j]
        sumf += v[j]*g(sumi)

    return sumf
```

Comment: Hi, this is my activation function in f. But I've to do the gradient of the function Error E (the first one in the picture).

Comment: you want to implement the first function ? E(w, pi) ?

Comment: I want to compute the Gradient of the function E(w, pi) because  i've just defined this function in Python but now i need to optimize, respect omega, with gradient algorithm.

Comment: you want to write the function F ?

Comment: i've already written the function, but i need the gradient of the error function E to optimize. I need to use algorithm gradient descent and before to use this i need the gradient of E

Comment: And you don't know how to calculate it? and by what parameter do you want the derivative?